# C++ External Memory Pattern Scanning

Tags: c++, memory, pattern-matching, arrays

im new to c++ and im trying to byte pattern scann a remote process, but somehow it doesnt work for me.
the program just crashes when it executes the pattern finding function.

this is the scanning function im using:

```
bool VerifyAddress(HANDLE hProcess, DWORD dwAddress, PBYTE bMask, char *szMask)
{
    PBYTE *pTemp = { 0 };

    for (int i = 0; *szMask; ++szMask, ++bMask, ++i)
    {
        if (!ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, reinterpret_cast<LPCVOID>(dwAddress + i), &pTemp, 2048, 0))
            return false;

        if (*szMask == 'x' && reinterpret_cast<char*>(pTemp) != reinterpret_cast<char*>(*bMask))
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}

DWORD ExternalFindPattern(HANDLE hProcess, PBYTE bMask, char *szMask)
{
    for (DWORD dwCurrentAddress = 0x401000; dwCurrentAddress < 0x7FFFFFF; dwCurrentAddress++)
        if (VerifyAddress(hProcess, dwCurrentAddress, bMask, szMask))
            return dwCurrentAddress;

    return -1;
}
```

and these are my parameters:

```
hProc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, processID);
char* Pattern = "\x65\x6E\x64\x6D\x69\x73\x73\x69\x6F\x6E\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x0B\x00\x00\x00\x65\x6E\x64\x4D\x69\x73\x73\x69\x6F\x6E";
char* Mask = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

DWORD signAdress = ExternalFindPattern(hProc, (PBYTE)Pattern, Mask);
```

im sorry if this is a obvious nooby question, but im stuck for hours now and i just cant get it to work

Comment: This appears to read 2048 bytes from the other process into a `sizeof(PBYTE *)` byte long buffer. No wonder it crashes like a rock. Read the [documentation for ReadProcessMemory()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680553(v=vs.85).aspx), then go and [talk to your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Thanks for that rubber duck link! Been programming for a year now and although I had heard of (and experienced) the concept of having an AHA moment while explaining my code, I never heard the rubber-duck reference.